# Can you do transitions in react-native with either inline styles or styled components

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components

Is it possible to do transitions in react native using StyleSheet or styled-components? I am trying the following with no luck.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export default class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper visible={visible}><Text>hello</Text>
    )
  }    
}

const Wrapper = styled.View`
  opacity: ${props => props.visible ? 1 : 0};
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
`

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition:'opacity 1s linear'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

React Native does not support react style transitions in this way, instead try the RN Animated View library, it works very similarly (and uses inline styles/components):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html

Answer (score 0):

React Native does support these kind of transitions, but only on the web. If you're rendering elsewhere, you'll need to use a different method.

Here's a quick example of how to do this in React Native Web:

```
<View style={condition ? style.true : style.false} />
```

```
true: { 
  opacity: 1, 
  transition:'0.5s, transform 0.5s' 
},
false: { 
  opacity: 0 
}
```

Comment: I tried it in the Expo Snack; it works on the web, but not the Android or iOS. The docs also don't mention such property.

Comment: That's good to know. I've only tried this on React Native Web. I'll update my answer the reflect that. Thank you.